# How to convert int to char in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I have included `linux/thie.h` and used `do_gettimeofday()` to get the time in seconds in integer type.
But I want to convert the result of seconds, minutes, hours to `char*` type.
How can I do this?

Btw, I can't include `stdlib.h` then use `itoa()` to convert.

I can read the result in the kernel by using the command **dmesg** now.  But I want to show the result in console by tty and I can only get string from kernel. How can I get the time information(it is variable) from kernel to console.

Comment: You mean `itoa` I take it.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I can read the result in the kernel by using the command **dmesg**.  But I want to show the result in console by tty and I can only get string from kernel. How can I get the time information(it is variable) from kernel to console.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function that is in the linux libc and does the same thing as atoi: `kstrtol`, see http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/kernel.h#L255

EDIT:

For the opposite conversion, use time_to_tm and then s(n)printf to format the string as you wish

Comment: He probably wants the opposite conversion.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake.
I want to convert int to char*